# How to play HTML5 Videos in native player on mobile?

Tags: html, video

I'm having following Video embedded in my website:

```
<video id="vid" data-src="/tasks/render/file/?method=inline&fileID=#local.child.getVideoFile()#">
    <source src="/tasks/render/file/?method=inline&fileID=#local.child.getVideoFile()#" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Which works fine. I have also wrapped the whole thing in a fancybox. Which opens the video in a lightbox-like overlay. Which is fine for desktop.

But now my question... Is there any way so I can open the video in the native video player of mobile devieds (iPhone, Android, Others)?

I've searched the HTML5 Video JavaScript Functions and the HTML5 Video HTML Attributes, but couldn't find anything.

To start the Video, I'm using this:

```
function play(vID) {
    document.getElementById('vid').play();
}
```

Comment: Is there some particular functionality you want from the Native player or is it just to get the video in full screen mode?

Comment: @Mick Yeah, basically I just want the video in full screen mode with all the default functionality (play, pause, rewind, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML5 actually has a FullSscreen API now - it is under development, as is often he case with new specs, but I think it is supported in most recent versions of iOS and Android.

The spec itself is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/fullscreen/, which links to the latest working version here (look at the strangely named 'See Instead' link): https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org

There are some example on this Mozilla page, although there is note that it needs to be updated so it would be worth you trying it out first.

The key functionality is JavaScript controlled, using the video element in the document. An example, from the above link, is:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("myvideo");
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
}
```

```html
<video controls id="myvideo">
  <source src="somevideo.webm"></source>
  <source src="somevideo.mp4"></source>
</video>
```